# ASP.NET Core Multiple JWTBearer authentication fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application running correctly using `JwtBearer` authentication configuration with Identity Server 4. All works fine until I wanted to have multiple authorities to be handled by the `[Authorize]` attribute.

I went through multiple threads and issues about that and took a look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-multiple-authentication-schemes the exact same code does not work and produces the following failure:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask1 creationTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler1.AuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at JQ.GrupoFontana.API.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__9_1>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\carlostorrecillas\Documents\git\jq.grupofontana.api\JQ.GrupoFontana.API\Startup.cs:line 264
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Request finished in 3073.2088ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

An example of the Authorization header is:

```
Authorization: Bearer …
```

Which is fine. The code in the API I have now is:

```
services.AddAuthentication("authority1")
            .AddJwtBearer("authority1", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:11710";
                options.Audience = "myaudience";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/hub", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("authority2", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:11910";
                options.Audience = "myaudience";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/hub", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("authority1", "authority2").RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                                                    .Build();
            });
```

You can ignore the `/hub` check stuff as that's to deal with tokens and SignalR. I added myself a breakpoint to each of the events just to see where is failing and the sequence is (note that `authority1` is the application running and `authority2` is currently stopped):

```
authority1.onMessageReceived - OK
authority1.onTokenValidated - OK
authority2.onMessageReceived - OK
authority2.onAuthenticationFailed - Method completes then I get the exception
```

I'm not sure if the problem is that I need to have all authorities running for some sort of validation/communication (I wouldn't have thought so) or whether there is an actual bug in the ASP.NET code itself - which hey, that could also be the case. I'm not sure if I miss any other configuration from the API point of view but I would say it's all set.

I'm using the standard `[Authorize]` attribute in my controllers without any authenticationschemes stuff in there - I have tried and that didn't work either.

If any of you has come across this issue I would really appreciate some help.

Many thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After a little bit more digging I could see this workaround:

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1680#issuecomment-370416251

setting the `context.NoResult()` on the OnAuthenticationFailed but I'm not sure if that's a valid configuration?

Comment: Guys, please be careful posting tokens. They contain sensitive data, such as email addresses or group names, from which you can get customer names and customer relation information. This in conjunction with the question leads to background knowledge very valuable for hackers.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just modified the question. Thanks for spotting this